# Joomla executes over 2700 database queries

Tags: php, sql, joomla, joomla2.5

I'm new to Joomla 2.5 and have this problem. Joomla executes over 2700 database queries on the homepage. I have not even a single clue how it could execute so much.

Here is a picture of the homepage. The amount of queries:
[image]

And this is the information page which only uses 109 queries (still a lot)
[image]

Comment: It might be possible that there is a loop coming from an extension being used on the homepage

Comment: It's a common issue with complex CMS-based sites. If your home page is static, your best (quickest) solution is to enable caching, so that it doesn't re-generate the page content every page load.

Comment: @Lodder I will take a look. The website became so slow I started to disable lots and lots of plugins. I will try it again now.

Comment: @Spudley Thanks i've tried the cache and it helped quite a lot however I dont think this is the correct way too fix this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer. The homepage was setup to show the virtuemart homepage. We put it so that it didn't show the virtuemart homepage but instead the one we made. So what the homepage did is load all the queries of virtuemart. We've put the menu item now to a blank page and the queries dropped by 2600. We've also enabled caching and that helped the site pretty much getting loaded in about 1.5 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

That is a ridiculous number of queries. Our home page with K2, a slideshow, a mega menu, 3 K2 modules, a search box, several custom HTML modules, and a Chronoforms module has a total of 73 queries.

Turn everything off then enable the modules and extensions one at a time until you find the problem extension. Once you have found the problem extension, uninstall it and get a replacement.

Comment: This is a common problem with VirtueMart sites, it's the heaviest shopping system I've seen.,